# Remove substring that contains certain pattern and ends with specific char

Tags: c++, regex, substring

For example I have a string like following:

> "VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=USv90B-7CzI; LOGIN_INFO=e486e37a395be3f0e3b3237d090a6829c1oAAAB7IjQiOiAiREVMRUdBVEVEIiwgIjciOiAwLCAiMSI6IDEsICIzIjogMjAxMTk0MTMwNiwgIjgiOiA2MDgwMTg0NTEzNjQsICIxMCI6IDIzOTYyMTEyODczNH0=; PREF=f5=30;HSID=AHuJQBOVR0lQoRt_3; APISID=QaParXGsQcEPCzKg/A1smCfYrfMjxvfEPT; YSC=Vm3Amq5loFM";

I want to remove all the patterns that contains *SID (HSID,APISID here) upto `';'`. I also want to remove substring "LOGIN_INFO= ....;"

So, output string should be `"VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=L80EDuHCEF8; PREF=f5=30";`

Following is the solution I have come up with but I think performance can be improved:

```
const char *str ="VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=USv90B-7CzI; LOGIN_INFO=e486e37a395be3f0e3b3237d090a6829c1oAAAB7IjQiOiAiREVMRUdBVEVEIiwgIjciOiAwLCAiMSI6IDEsICIzIjogMjAxMTk0MTMwNiwgIjgiOiA2MDgwMTg0NTEzNjQsICIxMCI6IDIzOTYyMTEyODczNH0=; PREF=f5=30;HSID=AHuJQBOVR0lQoRt_3; APISID=QaParXGsQcEPCzKg/A1smCfYrfMjxvfEPT; YSC=Vm3Amq5loFM"; 
     char *Cookie = NULL;
     cout << "original string is:\n" << str << "\n";
     int len = strlen(str)+1;
     cout << "length of original string is : " << len << "\n";
     Cookie = new char[strlen(str)];
     strncpy(Cookie,str,len);

     char *p1 = strstr(Cookie,"LOGIN_INFO");
     char *p2 = NULL;
     if(p1){
          p2 = strstr(p1,";")+1;
          while(*p2 == ' ') p2++;
     }
     if(p1 && p2)
          memmove(p1,p2,strlen(p2)+1);

     char *ID = strstr(Cookie,"SID"); 
     while( ID != NULL){
          char *start_pos = NULL, *end_pos = NULL;    
          while((*ID != ';') && (*ID != Cookie[0]) && (*ID != ' ')){
               --ID;
          }
          if(*ID == Cookie[0]) start_pos = ID;
          else start_pos = ID+1;
          end_pos = strstr(start_pos,";")+1;
          while(*end_pos == ' ')
               end_pos++;
          memmove(start_pos,end_pos,strlen(end_pos)+1);                                   
        //  } 
          /*else
               std::cout << "does not find substr " << "\n";*/

        //  cout << "modified string is :" << Cookie << "\n";
          ID = strstr(Cookie,"SID");
     }
          //cout << "final modified string is : " << Cookie << "\n";
     char *Cookie_modified = NULL;
     const char *pch = strstr(Cookie,"PREF");
     if(pch != NULL){
          const char *append = "&f2=8000000";
          int len = strlen(Cookie) + strlen(append) + 1;
          Cookie_modified = new char[len];
          strncpy(Cookie_modified,Cookie,len);
          Cookie_modified[len-1] = '\0';
          char *p = strstr(Cookie_modified,"PREF");
          strncpy(p+(strlen(p)),append,strlen(append));
          cout << "modified Cookie is : " << Cookie_modified << "\n";
      //    cout << "length of modified cookie is : " << strlen(Cookie_modified) << "\n";
     }

     else{
          cout << "do not find reference: " << "\n";
          const char *append = ";PERF=f2=8000000";
          int len = strlen(Cookie) + strlen(append) + 1;
          Cookie_modified = new char[len];
          Cookie_modified[len-1] = '\0';
          strcat(Cookie_modified,Cookie);
          strcat(Cookie_modified,append);
          cout << "case 2: modified Cookie is: " << Cookie_modified << "\n";

     }
     delete[] Cookie;
     delete[] Cookie_modified;     
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Definitely not [tag:c]...

Comment: *Following is the solution I have come up with but I think performance can be improved* - This should be posted on [codereview.se] if it works fine.

Comment: @LPs Code review questions are _not_ off-topic on SO. Sure you'll probably get a better reply on code review, but that doesn't make the question off-topic here. This has been discussed plenty on meta. Don't go inventing your own off-topic reasons, please. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Furthermore the Code Review site requires complete code, not just minimal examples as recommended here on SO, so this particular example would probably just get closed there.

Comment: `I think performance can be improved` is this a requirement from the program or a personal challenge? What makes you think that you *can* go faster easily?

Comment: [Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are not always a solution (sometimes it's the problem) but have you thought about using something like [`std::regex_replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace)?

Comment: this is personal challenge to improve performance. There may be better way of handling wildcard patterns

Comment: According to http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users the proper close reason is "Too broad". In this case also "Unclear what you are asking" applies, as I can't see any question here.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [std::regex_replace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) with the following regex:

```
([^\s]*SID[^;]*;|[^\s]*LOGIN_INFO[^;]*;)
```

And replace with empty string.

<kbd>[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cM9oM8/1)</kbd>